# What is the best way to extend the functionality of a class?

Tags: java, oop, classcastexception

Suppose I have a class called Task. I want to add some additional functionality to it, so I extend it. I do this by creating a class which extends Task.

```
public class TaskHelper extends Task
{
    public void getName()
    {
        ....
    }

    // more additional functionality
}
```

So, I start using this, and when I have a task object, and downcast to TaskHelper, I get a ClassCastException. So I understand that I can't downcast, and I try to create a copy constructo something like

```
public class TaskHelper extends Task
{
    TaskHelper(Task t)
    {
        Task(t);
    }
}
```

However, there is no copy constructor for Task, and I can't modify Task because it's a third-party class. What can I do?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the extend keyword. Extend makes TaskHelper as a subclass of Task. If you create an instance of TaskHelper you will already have all the methods that come along with your Task class.

Comment: You can only cast an object to a type that it actually is.  If you create an instance of `Task`, then it is a `Task`, but not a `TaskHelper`.  You need to change the code that constructs a new `Task` to construct a new `TaskHelper` instead, assuming that is within your control.

Comment: Because you are extending the `Task` class, you might want to look up the [super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword. Instead of copying the Task at the constructor, why not create the `Task` as a `TaskHelper` from the get-go?

Comment: You don't even need to "extend" any functionality from Class Task. Once you extends TaskHelper from Task. All methods and members are inherited to TaskHelper. It's taken care of implicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't modify Task because it's a third-party class

`Task` is an external dependency.  Instead of extending it, abstract it.  Something like this:

```
public class TaskHelper
{
    private Task task;

    public TaskHelper() {
        task = new Task();
    }

    // expose methods to delegate functionality to the private member
}
```

This de-couples your code from the third party code.  This brings about a number of benefits:

- You can simplify the interface to the third party component, exposing only the functionality you need or renaming the functionality to fit your domain specific language
- You can have `TaskHelper` implement an interface that can be easily mocked for unit testing or swapped out with other task implementations
- You can combine functionality with other related things and extend the component while still encapsulating it all to this object

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct you have a Task object somewhere in your code and want to provide some additional functionality to it by extending the Task class itself. Well for me it sounds like you need some kind of a wrapper class. I would create the TaskHelper like this:

```
public class TaskHelper {

    private Task taskObject;
    private String name;
    //Additional variables

    public TaskHelper(Task t) {
        taskObject = t;
    }

    public Task getTaskObject() {
        return taskObject;
    }

    //Setters, Getters and other methods working on the Task 
    object and additional variables

}
```

Now you can access your Task object via the Getter and work with it normally and you can use the newly provided methods to work on your Task object.

If you need the possibility to handle the TaskHelper as a normal Task object you need to extend the Task class, but thats easy too. Just create the TaskHelper class as you wrote and call the super() method (which calls the super classes constructor..) instead of your Task(t). Make sure that you provide all the information needed by the Task constructor in your TaskHelper constructor too.

I hope that helped you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

A better design is to use composition.    
                                              `public class TaskHelper { Task task; }` 
 
You will be able to use any kind of task using this approach. 
 Here, Task must be an interface.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question `Class Task` is a 3rd party class where you can't change its implementation. Have you tried whether you are able to "see" the methods of `Task` from `TaskHelper` after you extends `Task`?

```
class TaskHelper extends Task
{

}
```

The above code will inherit all methods and members from Task to TaskHelper implicitly. So you need not explicitly / manually try to extend the super class's methods anymore.

You also mentioned that there is no constructor from Class Task. However, there is always a default empty constructor which accepts no arguments.

Something addition: If you need to access to any of the super's class members or call the constructor from the super class, you may use the `super` keyword.

**Example on using "super":**

```
class A //A is super Class
{
   private int a;
   public A(int a)
   {
      this.a = a;
   }
}

class B extends A //B is sub Class
{
   private int b;
   public B(int a, int b) //a inherited from Class A
   {
      super(a); //use "super" to call the constructor from super class
      this.b = b;
   }
}
```